# Symfony form stepwizard without entity

Tags: php, forms, symfony

So I'm currently working on a project and basically I have to make sign up for a customer. A customer is either a person or an organization. If it's an organization, the customer has to provide the company name. Once the data is collected (the customer has submitted the form and all validations are well), the data is sent to an API which saves the user in the database (the entities are in a different project and both share the same database)

So, the sign up needs 2 steps, the first step is choose whether you're a person or organization and the second step is all the fields (with extra fields if you chose organization)

The code I'm building upon tried doing it in one FormType (this code isn't done by me, but the idea is something I would've done)

```
class SignUpFormType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
                $form = $event->getForm();

                if (!empty($_POST)) {
                    $data = $_POST['sign_up_form'];

                    if (isset($data['type'])) {
                        if ($data['type'] === 'company') {
                            $form
                                ->add('vatNr', TextType::class)
                                ->add('companyName', TextType::class);
                        }

                        $form
                            ->add('firstName', TextType::class)
                            ->add('lastName', TextType::class)
                            ->add('email', EmailType::class, [
                                'label' => 'Email:',
                                'label_attr' => ['class' => 'g-color-gray-dark-v2 g-font-weight-600 g-font-size-13'],
                                'required' => true,
                                'constraints' => [
                                    new NotBlank(['message' => 'Please fill in your email.'])
                                ]
                            ])
                            ->add('password', RepeatedType::class, [
                                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                                'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.',
                                'options' => ['attr' => ['class' => 'password-field']],
                                'required' => true,
                                'first_options' => [
                                    'label' => 'Password:',
                                    'label_attr' => ['class' => 'g-color-gray-dark-v2 g-font-weight-600 g-font-size-13']
                                ],
                                'second_options' => [
                                    'label' => 'Confirm Password:',
                                    'label_attr' => ['class' => 'g-color-gray-dark-v2 g-font-weight-600 g-font-size-13']
                                ],
                            ])
                            ->add('agree_tos', CheckboxType::class, [
                                'label' => 'I accept the Terms of Services',
                                'label_attr' => ['class' => 'form-check-inline u-check g-color-gray-dark-v2 g-font-weight-600 g-font-size-13'],
                                'attr' => ['class' => 'g-hidden-xs-up'],
                                'constraints' => [
                                    new IsTrue(['message' => 'You have to agree to our Terms of Services'])
                                ]
                            ])
                            ->add('Signup', SubmitType::class, ['attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-md u-btn-primary rounded g-py-13 g-px-25']]);
                    }
                } else {
                    $form
                        ->add('type', ChoiceType::class, [
                            'multiple' => false,
                            'choices' => [
                                'company' => 'company',
                                'person' => 'person'
                            ]
                        ])
                        ->add('next', SubmitType::class, ['attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-md u-btn-primary rounded g-py-13 g-px-25']]);
                }
            });
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefault('allow_extra_fields', true);
    }
}
```

The problem though is, if I go to my form, and I press the next button on the first step, it validates the fields on the second step. If I press Signup on the second step, it doesn't validate anything and just sees the form as valid.

Now I know there's a bundle to do a stepwizard (CraueFormFlowBundle) but this only works when using entities which I don't use.

Why does it validate step 2 when clicking on next in step 1 and how can I fix my issue (or is there a better way to do what I want?)

Comment: @emix I know I shouldn't use superglobals, I haven't changed that. As for the rest, how wouldn't I need a listener? How would I show fields / hide fields depending on the step then?

Comment: I would manage that in the Twig.

Comment: Care to make an example of how you'd do it? I'm not sure how I would do it in Twig